# Edit (and other bars) have a bad background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See the two attached screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm seeing this too, Mac OS X Firefox 3.6.13. It seems to be new, I haven't seen it until today.

Comment: Same with Chrome

Comment: Just saw it in FF3.6.12 for Linux (and Chrome)

Comment: I tested my change to the overlay text thing on almost all sites. I'm afraid I must've forgotten programmers.se :( sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.